# how to randomly list 5 authors with at least 3 published posts

Tags: list-authors

Bit of a newbie here...

As the title states, I am trying to generate a list of 5 random users (taken from authors, editors and administrators) who have published at least 3 posts each. (Also, I would like to exclude the author whose user ID is 4.)

I think I have managed to do all this (hacking together various solutions gratefully taken from useful previous posts here in wordpress.stackexchange!) but I am not sure if this is the best solution or if it's coded correctly. I use this feature on many pages throughout my website and am worried it might be too db query intensive.

```
<?php
global $wpdb;
$min_posts = 3; 
$user_ids = $wpdb->get_col("
SELECT `post_author` 
FROM
  (SELECT `post_author`, 
    COUNT(*) AS `count` 
    FROM {$wpdb->posts}
    WHERE `post_status`='publish'  
    GROUP BY `post_author`) 
AS `stats`
WHERE `count` >= {$min_posts} AND post_author !=4;");
shuffle($user_ids);

for($someNumber = 1; $someNumber <= 5; $someNumber++) {
$user = get_userdata($user_ids[$someNumber]); ?>

      <?php echo get_avatar( $user->ID, '60' );?>
      <h7><a href="<?php echo get_author_posts_url( $user->ID ); ?>">
        <?php echo $user->display_name ;?></a></h7>
      <hr>
<?php
}
unset($user_ids);
?>
```

Any help truly appreciated, many thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use [`count_many_users_posts()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/count_many_users_posts).

```
$args = array(
    'exclude' => array( 4, ),
    'fields' => 'ID',
);
$users = get_users( $args );
$user_posts = count_many_users_posts( $users );
foreach( $user_posts as $user => $posts ) {
    if( $posts < 3 ) {
        unset( $user_posts[$user] );
    }
}
$user_ids = array_keys( $user_posts );
shuffle( $user_ids );
for( $i = 0; $i <=4; $i++ ) {
    $user = get_userdata( $user_ids[$i] );
    // display your user info here
}
```

#### Reference

- [`count_many_users_posts()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/count_many_users_posts)
- [`get_users()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_users)
- [`array_keys()`](http://php.net/array_keys)

Comment: Useful to learn about count_many_users_posts(), thanks! For anyone else who is wrapping their head around this, thefunction is appropriate if handling large number of users, while count_user_posts instead is good if handling one user.

Answer (score 1):

### Basic Query

The following query will give you the five users with the most posts in a site. Using the `HAVING` and `COUNT` will be much faster than other queries. Especially faster than built in multi purpose WP queries.

```
global $wpdb;

$postCountSQL = <<<SQL
    SELECT post_author, COUNT( * ) AS count
        FROM {$wpdb->posts}
    GROUP BY post_author
    HAVING COUNT( * ) > 3
    ORDER BY count DESC 
    LIMIT 0 , 5
SQL;

$postCount = $wpdb->get_results( $postCountSQL );
```

### Random results

Now that you want to have them randomly. It's actually quite easy using the MySQL function `RAND()`:

```
SELECT post_author, COUNT( * ) AS count
    FROM {$wpdb->posts}
GROUP BY post_author
HAVING COUNT( * ) > 3
ORDER BY RAND() DESC
LIMIT 0 , 5
```

### Excluding

To exclude a specific user by ID, we can use the `NOT` statement:

```
SELECT post_author, COUNT( * ) AS count
    FROM {$wpdb->posts}
GROUP BY post_author
HAVING COUNT( * ) > 3
    AND NOT post_author = {$id}
ORDER BY RAND( ) DESC 
LIMIT 0 , 5
```

### The Plugin

To summon that in a small mu-plugin (so it is available per default on every site):

```
<?php
/**
 * Plugin Name: (#115930) Random User Post Count
 * Plugin URI:  http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/115930/how-to-randomly-list-5-authors-with-at-least-3-published-posts
 * Description: Lists five random users and their posts count. Can exclude users by ID.
 * Author:      Franz Josef Kaiser <wecodemore@gmail.com>
 * Author URI:  http://unserkaiser.com
 */
defined( 'ABSPATH' ) OR exit;

function wpse115930UserPostCountRand( $minCount = 3, $userIDs = array(), $limit = 5 )
{
    ! is_array( $userIDs ) AND $userIDs = array( $userIDs );

    global $wpdb;

    $sql = <<<SQL
SELECT post_author, COUNT( * ) AS count
    FROM {$wpdb->posts}
GROUP BY post_author
HAVING COUNT( * ) > %d %s
ORDER BY RAND( ) DESC
LIMIT 0 , %d
SQL;

    $exclude = "";
    ! empty( $userIDs ) AND $exclude = $wpdb->prepare(
        " AND NOT post_author IN ( %s ) ",
        join( ",", $userIDs )
    );

    return $wpdb->get_results( $wpdb->prepare( $sql, $minCount, $exclude, $limit ) );
}
```

You can now simply call `wpse115930UserPostCountRand( 3, array( 4 ), 5 );` anywhere in your templates to get the users who have a minimum of 5 posts, don't have the ID of `4` and limit the result to `3` users. As you can see the second argument is an array, so expanding the results to exclude more users is easy. The same goes for a different amount of users or minimum posts.

### Caching results

As already mentioned, you could use the Transients API. Another and maybe even better option would be to use the [WP Object Cache](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Object_Cache) in above plugin. In case some sort of persistent cache like OpCode or MEMcache is involved, it will cache it to disk as well.

Have fun :)

Comment: I appreciate your input, it helped me learn about caching and query syntax!

Comment: @user10331 You're welcome. But have you actually tried the plugin I added? If not, give it a try and compare the results and the execution time with the other answer(s). You'll see that this plugin uses the shortest possible way, uses the least memory and has the shortest execution time. Just try it and compare the results.

Answer (score 0):

> I use this feature on many pages throughout my website and am worried it might be too db query intensive.

On pretty much everything I do, if I don't need "real-time" data, I use transients to cache my XML, JSON and Database calls.  Check out [the Transient API](http://codex.wordpress.org/Transients_API).

Comment: Did not know about transient API, thanks. Quite versatile!